# checkbox not checked and rowCallback not working on datatables responsive

Tags: jquery, checkbox, responsive-design, datatables

I am using datatables and responsive extension, I've got some checkboxs which represent boolean data (0 , 1) in my db. I use `rowCallback` `data` to check the checkbox. But when the page is resized or it is in responsive mode it shows column as child, detailed list, the checkbox is not checked and `rowCallback` not triggered and data is undefined..!

```
        table=$('#mytable').DataTable({
        "sDom": "<'row DTTTHeader'<'col-sm-7'Tl><'col-sm-5 no-padding'f>>t<'row DTTTFooter'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
        processing: true,
        serverSide: false,
        deferRender: true,
        responsive: true,                                   
        ajax: {
            url: '/my/url/show',
            method: 'POST',                  

        },
        columns: [
            {data: "id", searchable: false, visible: false, className: "never"},
            {data: "product", searchable: true, visible: true},
            {data: "category", searchable: true, visible: true},
            {data: "available", searchable: true, visible: true},
            {data: "sold", searchable: true, visible: true},
            {data: "active", searchable: false,
                render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                    if ( type === 'display' ) {
                        return '<label><input class="checkbox colored-danger active" type="checkbox" disabled><span class="text"></span></label>';
                    }
                    return data;
                }, 
                className: "dt-center"                       
            }
            {
              data: null,
              defaultContent: '<button class="btn btn-info btn-xs edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> edit</button> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs del" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> remove</button>',
              targets: -1 ,
              searchable: false,
              orderable: false,
            }          
        ],
        rowCallback: function ( row, data ) {
            $('input.active', row).prop( 'checked', data.active == 1 );
        }                    
    });
```

buttons and checkboxs aren't working due to undefined row `data.id` and `data.active`

jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/s95q26pn/4/

info: try to resize the window to see the responsive mode of datatables and then check row number 2 for example, the active checkbox is not checked while it should be

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle showing the issue?

Comment: sorry I couldn't manage to run it on jsFiddle.. [http://jsfiddle.net/s95q26pn/](http://jsfiddle.net/s95q26pn/)

Comment: you're missing a comma in your `columns` array that is causing an error in the jsfiddle. See http://jsfiddle.net/s95q26pn/2/ is that missing in your actual code as well?

Comment: thanks.. not actually, I tried to demonstrate it... [http://jsfiddle.net/s95q26pn/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/s95q26pn/4/)

Comment: Not sure what version of DataTables you are using, nor if this is germane, but a very recent release of their Editor product not that a bug was fixed with respect to the checkbox. Perhaps the bug impacted DataTables too and if you are not running 1.10.10, you may want to try upgrading.